# HTTP Request (with SSL) JAVA vs AJAX

Tags: java, ajax, ssl, https, request

When I execute the request `https://domain/file.php`

- From JAVA (Android) I have exception : `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException` (Trust anchor for certification path not found) and the respense is not returned
- From Ajax or PHP The respense is returned
- From the browser The respense is returned and the infos of certification is not found

I know that there is problem with the certification and my questions are :

1. What the diffrence between JAVA and AJAX, PHP, Browser?
2. If I don't implement the check of certification in AJAX, there security problems?

Answer (score 0):

An Ajax request is made by a web browser in java script. This behaviour is controlled by the web browser such as firefox or chrome. If you webbrowser does not trust the  https://domain/ it will cause an error.

You should always implement ssl certificate checks on production systems as this prevents Man in the middle attacks and eve dropping on your communications